# How to clear form after post?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app using Ionic. After send values of form I want to clear form but I can't do this.

How could I do this ?

**form**

```
<form name="Empresa">
    <div class="list">
                                <label class="item item-input" 
                                       ng-class="{'has-errors':Empresa.nomeemp.$invalid, 'no-errors':Empresa.nomeemp.$valid}">
                                    <input type="text" 
                                           placeholder="Nome" 
                                           name="nomeemp" 
                                           ng-model="Empresa.nome" 
                                           ng-required="true">
                                </label>
                                <div class="error-container"
                                     ng-show="(Empresa.nomeemp.$dirty || !Empresa.nomeemp.$pristine)"
                                     ng-messages="Empresa.nomeemp.$error">
                                    <div ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html"></div>
                                </div>                            
    </div>

<button type="button" class="button button-block button-energized"  
                    ng-disabled="Empresa.$invalid" ng-click="addEmpresa(Empresa);">Cadastrar</button>

</form>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.addEmpresa = function(Empresa){      
      var _pathFile = document.getElementById("smallimage").src;
      var _fileName = _pathFile.substr(_pathFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      if(_fileName === 'no-image.png'){
        $ionicLoading.show({ template: APP_MESSAGES.escolhaImagem, noBackdrop: true, duration: 2000 });
      }else{
          $ionicLoading.show();
          EmpresaAPIService.addEmpresa(Empresa).then(function (data) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            var retorno = JSON.parse(data.response);
            if(retorno.status === 0){
              $ionicLoading.show({ template: retorno.msg, noBackdrop: true, duration: 2000 });
            }
            if(retorno.status === 1){ 
              //clear form
              delete Empresa;           
              Empresa.$setPristine();
              Empresa.$setUntouched(); 

              $ionicLoading.show({ template: retorno.msg, noBackdrop: true, duration: 2000 });

            }

          }, function (err) {        
             $ionicLoading.hide();           
          }, function (progress) {
             // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
          });

      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you currently observe? If you clear the value that is being bound to on your template then it should appear cleared.

Comment: Just empty the scope variable `$scope.Empresa={}` after form submission.

Comment: ng-model data binds to Empresa.nome. So if you wan't to clear the input field set the value of Empresa.nome to an empty string or null. Obviously, do this AFTER the logic in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller after you do your submission logic, set `$scope.Empresa.noma = '';` as that's what is being bound to your form in your application.

edit: `setPristine()` should also work.